# Application_Start event not firing when published

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, global-asax

I researched a lot but got nothing...

`Application_Start` event is not firing when published the site. However it works fine in localhost. After publishing i got the App_global.asax.dll and App_GlobalResources.compiled in Bin folder and also have PrecompiledApp.config at root.

Answer (score 4):

Application_Start event is fired when the Application is ran for the first time. It has nothing to do with restarting machine or restarting IIS. Did you tried in making a new sample app and test that Application_Start event of that application ran well or not. If yes then you application configuration is corrupted someway.

maybe restarting your application pool can help you.

Comment: Thanks Masoud for the reply.                                     Yes, its working fine in localhost but once website is published the event is not firing. Any clue..

Comment: what is your windows version?

Comment: Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition

Comment: Consider my scenerio: ** protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) { logfile.ErrorLog("UserErrorLog\\UserErrorLog.txt", "Application_Start method executed at " + System.DateTime.Now); DoSomeWork(); logfile.ErrorLog("UserErrorLog\\UserErrorLog.txt", "Application_Start method execution ends at " + System.DateTime.Now); }**

Comment: this problem is likely for your application server not your application.

Comment: What may be the problem? Please suggest.

Comment: @AshishKumar Hey man, were you able to fix this issue? I having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it's this event is fired as expected, but since you're executing a precompiled web, and in release mode, there're no debugging symbols - in the case of trying to remotely debug your application -.

Another possible reason is it's firing, but some exception is thrown within Application_Start handler, and since this is called once per application life-cycle, you'll need to recycle application's pool or restart the entire IIS.

Comment: There is no such exception. I'm logging in text file once the control comes inside Application_Start event. The problem is control iteself is not coming to this event. Consider my scenerio : protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        logfile.ErrorLog("UserErrorLog\\UserErrorLog.txt", "Application_Start method executed at " + System.DateTime.Now);
        DoSomeWork();
        logfile.ErrorLog("UserErrorLog\\UserErrorLog.txt", "Application_Start method execution ends at " + System.DateTime.Now);


    }

Comment: I can't help you with this limited info, I tried to give you basic hints.

Comment: This is the sample code which i'm trying to do. Works perfect in local machine but when published in debug mode the event Application_Start is not firing. I checked if there is any exception, but unfortunately there is no exception. `protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) { logfile.ErrorLog("UserErrorLog\\UserErrorLog.txt", "Application_Start method executed at " + System.DateTime.Now); DoSomeWork(); logfile.ErrorLog("UserErrorLog\\UserErrorLog.txt", "Application_Start method execution ends at " + System.DateTime.Now); }`                       Please ask if I'm not clear.

Comment: Who knows man, and posting coding in comments is not a good place for analyzing your problem.. It'll be hard to determine without executing your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, told in other comments:

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    logfile.ErrorLog("UserErrorLog\\UserErrorLog.txt", "Application_Start method executed at " + System.DateTime.Now);
    DoSomeWork();
    logfile.ErrorLog("UserErrorLog\\UserErrorLog.txt", "Application_Start method execution ends at " + System.DateTime.Now);
}
```

Writing to `UserErrorLog\\UserErrorLog.txt` will be problematic in a normal IIS setup, it will attempt to write somewhere within `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\Inetsrv` which is the executing directory of IIS. You need to either specify an absolute path (`C:\Logs\...`) or using [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to resolve an application based path (`HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/Logs/...")`)